# HABTM checkboxes unpermitted params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I cant save selected boxes in my remote form.

I need select some companies and save in invitations table.

As print:
[image]

I have tried add in  permited params company_ids: [] , company_ids => []  and { company_ids=>[ ] } .. nothing work..

Remote form:

```
<%= form_tag @invitations, remote:true do |f| %>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Nome Fantasia</th>
            <th>Razão Social</th>
            <th>CNPJ</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Cidade</th>
            <th>Ramo de atividade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%= hidden_field_tag "invitation[company_ids][]", nil %>
        <% @companies.each do |company| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= check_box_tag "invitation[company_ids][]", company.id, id: dom_id(company) %></td>
                <td><%= company.nomefantasia %></td>
                <td><%= company.razaosocial %></td>
                <td><%= company.cnpj %></td>
                <td><%= company.state.estado %></td>
                <td><%= company.city.cidade %></td>
                <td><%= company.category.nome %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
        <%= button_tag(:type => 'submit', :class => 'btn btn-success btn-lg') do %>
                    Enviar <i class="fa fa-send-o"></i>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Model controller to create
Invitations_Controller.rb

```
    def invitation_params
params.require(:invitation).permit(:representative_id,:company_id,:user_id,:quote_id,company_ids: [] )
    end
```

Message error :

```
Started POST "/invitations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-14 00:29:21 -0300
Processing by InvitationsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "invitation"=>{"company_ids"=>["", "2", "3"]}}
Unpermitted parameters: company_ids
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `invitations` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-07-14 03:29:21', '2014-07-14 03:29:21')
   (81.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/invitations/7
Completed 302 Found in 89ms (ActiveRecord: 82.0ms)
```

Comment: your error is unknown attributes not unpermitted parameters

Comment: @bcd thx bro.. posted correctly error

Comment: Why do you have `company_id` too in your `permitted params`?

Comment: Try removing the `company_id` from your `invitation_params`.`params.require(:invitation).permit(:representative_id,:user_id,:quote_id,company_ids: [] )`

Answer (score 0):

I think `@Pavan` is right -

---

Your params look good:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "invitation"=>{"company_ids"=>["", "2", "3"]}}
```

This means when you call your `strong_params` method, you'll have to call the following:

```
params.require(:invitation).permit(company_ids: [])
```

--

Since you're only updating the associative `HABTM` data, why don't you try just updating the `strong_params` method to *only* accept the `company_ids` attribute?

--

Other than this, I think your system looks okay